# Create a sortable table from other tables in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document with three different sheets. The first and second sheets each contain an identically formatted tables with different information on each. Let's call them shopping lists.

Sheet 1: Things Mom Wants to Buy
Contains a table with Item, Quantity, Best place to purchase, etc.

Sheet 2: Things Dad Wants to Buy
Contains a table with Item, Quantity, Best place to purchase, etc.

I want the third sheet -- "Everything We Need to Buy" -- to contain a table aggregated from the other two, containing all items that are on both lists (we don't need to worry about duplicates). I would prefer this third table be sortable, but at the very least I do not want it to have rows of blank spaces.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends on how you plan to use your third sheet. But here's one solution to get you started, assuming you have at least one column in `Sheet 1` that is guaranteed to contain values for every row. For the purposes of my example, we'll assume that column is `Sheet1!$B:$B`.

Our formula will go in `Sheet3!A2`, right below the column header, then be filled right and down.

At first, you'll want to get the contents of `Sheet1`. That's easy: `=Sheet1!A2`. The relative reference will copy the whole table over.

At one point you need to switch over to `Sheet2`. How do you (or, rather, the formula) know when? We can count the number of rows in `Sheet1` like this: `=COUNTA(Sheet1:$B:$B)`--note we're using the column guaranteed to have values for each row. This is counting the non-blank cells in that column.

Using that row count, we can compare the current (`Sheet3`) row to the `Sheet1` row count to determine whether it's time to switch. You can get the current row with `=ROW()` (remember to subtract 1 for the head row).

If we put that together, we get our switch-over check:

`=IF((ROW()-1)<COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!A2,[switch-over formula])`

How do we tell it what cell to go to, since we can't use the same method as we did for `Sheet1`? We offset the same type of relative reference (i.e. `Sheet2!A2`) by subtracting the `Sheet1` row count, then adding 1 (again, for headers).

`=IF((ROW()-1)<COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!A2,OFFSET(Sheet2!A2,-COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)+1,0))`

That will add the tables without any spaces.

## Challenges:

#### 0s

If you fill the formula past the length of both tables--and you'll probably want to, so if you add rows you don't have to update `Sheet3`--you'll get 0s in the cells. To prevent this, you can check against the count of items in `Sheet2` in your formula and add an empty string if the current row is greater than the sum of items in both sheets.

`=IF((ROW()-1)<COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!A2,IF((ROW()+1)>(COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)+COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B)),"",OFFSET(Sheet2!A2,-COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)+1,0)))`

#### Performance

If you have under 10,000 items total, you probably don't need to worry about performance. But if this list gets really big, the constant checks on sheet counts will bog down the sheet. To get around this, make another sheet where you use two cells to calculate the counts for `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, then reference those from your formula in `Sheet3`. They will be calculated just once each as Excel updates the dependency tree.

#### Sorting

Sorting in `Sheet3` is technically possible using the `SMALL` function, but it's probably not worth it. If you really want it sorted, use a pivot table on the columns from `Sheet3`. The only caviat: you'll need to refresh your pivot table each time data is changed, or else set up a macro to do it for you.

Comment: I've input this as an array formula, but it's filled the table up to the length of the Sheet1 table with the value in Sheet1!A2  (every cell in all columns), and then it says "#REF!" for the length of the table on Sheet2. I didn't worry about the "0s" section of your answer -- my sheet isn't actually for a grocery list, and the number of elements on it can't change so that's not a concern -- so I'm using the formula right above the "Challenges:" header.

Comment: This isn't an array formula so you shouldn't need to worry about that. But if the one above challenges is working but not the one in the "0s" section, I recommend using the Formulas->Evaluate Formula to see where exactly the error is coming from.